# Display records in the read area of Screen

Tags: wicket-6, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6, wicketstuff

I want to display some records in the read  area of GUI screen after performing some action.
I have some input fields in the screen which should be entered by users and based on the entry, I am calling a function from database which is displaying the result correctly as a feedback message on the screen.

But i want to have this result in the read area of screen. Any help is appreciated.Something like below

-----------Input fields--------

Name :

Department :

City :

Rank  :

```
                   Submit Button(this will call my logic based on input)
```

-----------------------This i call as Read Area after the submit button(Expectation)------------------

Name :  XYZ

Department : ABC

City : YYY

Rank : 4

Comment: What have you tried ? What kind of problems you have faced ?

Comment: @martin-g , I have tried with feedback panel of webmarkupcontainer.But the problem i am facing here to display in some sort of order.As this attribute is displaying at the top of the screen which i don't want, instead the remaining input fields will be as it is..and the result should display at the bottom in read area of screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Wicket Panel for the result.

Initially this Panel will be invisible:

```
ResultPanel resultPanel = new ResultPanel("resultPanel", new Model<Result>());  // null model object
resultPanel.setVisible(false); 
resultPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

Later after successfully saving into the database you will make it visible:

```
 @Override public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
     Result result = saveInDB(...);

     resultPanel.setModelObject(result);
     resultPanel.setVisible(result != null);
     target.add(resultPanel);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used "span wicket:id" and it serve my purpose.thank you all.